# Does returning a pointer to the same variable leaks memory?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, sdl, sdl-2

Does this code leak memory?

```
SDL_Texture* texture;
SDL_Surface* surface;
int infinity = 99999999;
for (int i=0; i<infinity; i++) {
   surface = IMG_Load("path/to/image.png");
   texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, surface);
}
```

Do I need do destroy (clear from memory) the surface and texture every time before I reassign the variable?

Comment: Yes you should, keep in mind to put a `NULL` pointer check.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. [`SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface`](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface) has a corresponding [`SDL_DestroyTexture`](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_DestroyTexture) and [`SDL_FreeSurface`](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_FreeSurface) methods that must be called.

Note on the page for `SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface`

> The surface is not modified or freed by this function.

Per @bathsheba, a `std::unique_ptr` can be used to do the deletion.

```
auto SDLTextureDeleter = [](SDL_Texture* pTexture) { if(pTexture) SDL_DestroyTexture(pTexture); };
std::unique_ptr<SDL_Texture, decltype(SDLTextureDelter)>(texture, SDLTextureDeleter); // This will call SDL_DestroyTexture when the unique pointer is destructed.
```

For bonus points, you can add a specialization for `std::default_delete<T>` in `namespace std` that handles `SDL_****` pointers and avoid declaring the deleter seperately.

Comment: If you show the OP how to wire that into `std::unique_ptr` (using a custom deleter) then I'll *massively* upvote this.

Comment: might want to note [`IMG_Load`](https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/docs/SDL_image_11.html#SEC11)'s documentation explicitly states " Don't forget to SDL_FreeSurface the returned surface pointer when you are through with it."

Comment: As per @Bathsheba's comment, you can create a `std::unique_ptr` that handles destruction for you, with very little code. For the `IMG_Load` and `SDL_FreeSurface` functions, you may do the following: `std::unique_ptr<SDL_Surface, decltype(&SDL_FreeSurface)> surface{IMG_Load("path/to/image.png"), SDL_FreeSurface};`

Comment: @jaggedSpire nice to know

Answer (score 1):

The *only* thing that causes memory leaks in C++ is a `new` that is not balanced with a `delete` or a `new[]` that is not balanced with a `delete[]`. (Also, if you use `malloc` &c., then you *must* use `free`.)

In your case it looks like `IMG_Load` and `SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface` *do* allocate memory, so yes I'd say it does leak. Consult the function documentation to see how you need to manage the release of any memory allocated. Normally, if a library allocates memory then it provides a means of releasing it. This is because memory management is done by the C++ runtime and that can vary from compilation to compilation.

Comment: Not true. There are other ways to allocate (and leak) memory. Examples include `brk()`/`sbrk()` on UNIX and `CoTaskMemAlloc()`, `GlobalAlloc()`, `HeapAlloc()`, `LocalAlloc()` & `VirtualAlloc()` on Windows. And even more if you get creative.  Arguably these are all platform specific, but they do prove that there *are* other ways to allocate/leak.

Comment: In the context of standard c++ (as opposed to an arbitrary os which offers a c++ api) , my answer holds true.

Comment: @jesperjuhl touche

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You should free memory using SDL_FreeSurface function.

In this case I suggest to use smart pointer to free memory 'automatically':

```
std::unique_ptr<SDL_Surface, decltype(&SDL_FreeSurface)> surface{IMG_Load(path.c_str()), SDL_FreeSurface};
```

To access the smart pointer use:

```
surface.get()
```